# Accuracy comparison between Environment.TickCount and DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, date

I saw a similar question being asked somewhere in this site, but it did not quite answer my question.
As mentioned in the question, what is the most accurate method to get the current time? or are these methods the same when it comes to accuracy?
also, i am not going to run my system for days, so there's no worry of Tickcount getting re-set.
Also I cannot use StopWatch class functionality in my code, due to the way it is designed. So I just want to know form the above two methods, which one is more accurate.

/Surangika

Comment: "Also I cannot use StopWatch class functionality in my code, due to the way it is designed."? Could you explain that please

Answer (score 1):

Both Environment.TickCount and DateTime.Now as based on the system timer according to the documentation so they should be equally accurate.